Generics, type T of interface interpreted as value T or **T when used as pointer
I am new to Go programming and trying to utilize the generic API of Go. I want to implement the IEntity interface and use implemented structs to abstract Mongo DB collections.
I implemented the IEntity interface for User type using a pointer receiver and i
type User struct {
    Id       string `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
    Username string `bson:"username" json:"username" binding:"required"`
    Email    string `bson:"email" json:"email" binding:"required,email"`
    Password string `bson:"password" json:"password" binding:"required"`
}

func (e *User) GetId() string {
    return e.Id
}

func (e *User) SetId(id string) {
    e.Id = id
}

type IEntity interface {
    GetId() string
    SetId(id string)
}

And I want to use it like below
type MongoDbContext struct {
    *mongo.Database
}

type MongoCollection[T models.IEntity] struct {
    *mongo.Collection
}

// It gives an error when using User type as value type like *MongoCollection[models.User] since it is implemented using a pointer receiver
func (ctx *MongoDbContext) Users() *MongoCollection[*models.User] {
    return &MongoCollection[*models.User]{
        ctx.Database.Collection("users"),
    }
}

func (col *MongoCollection[T]) FirstOrDefault(filter any) *T {
    var result T
    err := col.FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&result)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    return &result
}

When I want to use the FirstOrDefault method it indicates that the function returns **models.User since I used the type as *MongoCollection[*models.User] and also *T in the method.
When I use it as T Go interprets as Value Type and does not allow me to utilize pointer functionalities
So I could not achieve to return *models.User from FirstOrDefault methods.
I please you help to solve my confusion.

Yes, when I change the return Statement to T, the function will return *models.User but Go is recognizing T as a value type (models.User) and it does not allow me to return nill. at the outside of the function, it recognizes the pointer (*models.User). I guess it is a bug with the compiler or extension(vs code), but using value type T does not allow me to use the benefits of pointers even if it references pointers.
